# jQuery Mobile Form database update stopped working why

Tags: php, html, jquery-mobile

I need some help. I have been developing a form which updates a database. It was all working fine using the jQuery Mobile form and then suddenly it has all stopped working. I have stripped the form down the the bare minimum and still its not working. When I click on update the information is placed the the browser as shown below.
update_db.php?niamh=1
but the database is not updated. If I click on refresh it updates and displays success. 
If I remove all the jQuery header links it all works ok, so this is a jQuery problem. Sadly this was all working ok a couple of hours ago. code below, can any one please help.

HTML form

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>

    <form action="update_db.php" method="GET">
    <input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" name="niamh" id="switch" value="1">
     <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Update">
     </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

php update_db.php

```html
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password="14Odiham"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="heating"; // Database name 
$tbl_name = "roomControl";

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$niamh = (isset($_GET['niamh'])) ? 1 : 0;

// Insert data into mysql 
$sql = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET niamh=$niamh WHERE id=1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>
<?php
//close connection
mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<form action="update_db.php" method="GET" data-ajax="false">
```